# Pie chart Vega lite : How to align labels & numbers?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I'm trying to get this look [Pie Ideal label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Rep.png) and at this point, i get : [My try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YucJS.png)

Labels are not aligned with numbers.
When i try "align", everything is going left or right...but not as attended. As a matter of fact, I need labels to be next to the outcircle whatever position it is... and aligned with numbers.

[link to my pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv6jnMWzcGS6aWvMr9?e=RdsbUA)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should get you close enough.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "Points_calculation",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "ORDER",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {
        "field": "ORDER",
        "order": "descending"
      },
      "legend": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "******RING BACKGROUND******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Name labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 110,
        "align": {
          "expr": "scale('theta', ((datum.Points_calculation_end - datum.Points_calculation_start)/2) + datum.Points_calculation_start ) > PI  ?'right':'left'"
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Name",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Values_Labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Points_calculation",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ohh... Wonderfull !! I wouldn't have been even close from this... Thanks very much...

Comment: Can you explain the use to write :
datum.Points_calculation_end
(- datum.Points_calculation_start + datum.Points_calculation_start )=0 ?
Thanks

Comment: That is taking the midpoint of the angle for each slice. End minus beginning plus beginning to get the overall position. Don't forget to mark as solved. Thanks